# Update MongoDB sub document element based on the Condition using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

**Here is my JSON Array**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("563b57c84abf457b395076f0"),
"project_id" : "563b57c84abf45ce1f5076f1",
"project_task" : [ 
    {
        "switch" : "Ball",
        "deviceId" : "dasdqwdf124",
        "slot" : "2344",
        "MigrationStartDate" : "",
        "MigrationEndDate" : "",
        "MigrationStatus" : "",
        "task_id" :12
    }
  ]
}
```

In this array `project_id` and `task_id` (Sub Document element) values are unique.
 So in this case i need update my sub document element one at a time 
 When *`project_id`* and *`task_id`* are equals to given values.
So far i used update function with *and* condition  and *`findAndModify()`* function but never worked for me.
**Here is my Query using `findAndModify()`**

```
findAndModify(array('project_id' => "$projectId", 'project_task' => array('task_id' => "$taskId")), array('$set' => array("$column" => "$value")))
```

Please help me out

Comment: Fairly simple mistake here, look into dot notation for querying: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents

Comment: Yeah, I found simple solution, Specific  the element for the array!                                   update(array("project_id" => "$projectId"), array('$set' => array("project_task.$elementKey.$column" => "$value")))